# Entity Framework Core : cannot evaluate GroupBy expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

I have this query :

```cs
DbSet<UserRole>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 1407)
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Roles_part>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.RoleId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.Id, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            userId = _l.EmployeeId, 
            roleId = _r.Id, 
            roleName = _r.Name
         })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Permission>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.roleId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.RoleId, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            roleId = _l.roleId, 
            roleName = _l.roleName, 
            userId = _l.userId, 
            resourceName = _r.Resource.Name, 
            resourceId = _r.Resource.Id, 
            Write = _r.Write, 
            Delete = _r.Delete, 
            Modify = _r.Modify, 
            Read = _r.Read
         })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Employee>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.userId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.Id, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            resourceName = _l.resourceName, 
            resourceId = _l.resourceId, 
            Write = _l.Write, 
            Read = _l.Read, 
            Modify = _l.Modify, 
            Delete = _l.Delete, 
            roleId = _l.roleId, 
            roleName = _l.roleName, 
            userId = _r.Id, 
            userFirstName = _r.FirstName, 
            userLastName = _r.LastName
         })
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: resultSet => new { userId = resultSet.userId }, 
        elementSelector: resultSet => resultSet)
    .ToList()'
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I know that `GroupBy` is the issue because if I remove it I can see my results.

The relations are as follows

```
Employee 1-* UserRole *-1 Role 1-* Permission 1-* Resource
```

I'm interested in getting the following structure

```
User : 1
   Role : 1
     Resource : 1,
     Resource : 2,
   Role : 2 
     Resource : 3,
     Resource : 4,
```

So a user can have a list of roles a role can have a list of resources that is extracted based on role permissions.

Comment: @GertArnold I've added the version in the question

Comment: If you use navigation properties instead of joins the query becomes much easier to read and it's easier to find a way to write it without GroupBy.

Answer (score 0):

I think GroupBy isn't being translated into SQL.

Try to perform the grouping after retrieving the data from the database. maybe use `ToList()` to retrieve the data from the database and later perform the grouping operation on the resulting list.

```
var result = DbSet<UserRole>()
    .Where(x => x.EmployeeId == 1407)
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Roles_part>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.RoleId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.Id, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            userId = _l.EmployeeId, 
            roleId = _r.Id, 
            roleName = _r.Name
        })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Permission>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.roleId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.RoleId, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            roleId = _l.roleId, 
            roleName = _l.roleName, 
            userId = _l.userId, 
            resourceName = _r.Resource.Name, 
            resourceId = _r.Resource.Id, 
            Write = _r.Write, 
            Delete = _r.Delete, 
            Modify = _r.Modify, 
            Read = _r.Read
        })
    .Join(
        inner: DbSet<Employee>(), 
        outerKeySelector: _l => _l.userId, 
        innerKeySelector: _r => _r.Id, 
        resultSelector: (_l, _r) => new { 
            resourceName = _l.resourceName, 
            resourceId = _l.resourceId, 
            Write = _l.Write, 
            Read = _l.Read, 
            Modify = _l.Modify, 
            Delete = _l.Delete, 
            roleId = _l.roleId, 
            roleName = _l.roleName, 
            userId = _r.Id, 
            userFirstName = _r.FirstName, 
            userLastName = _r.LastName
        })
    .ToList() // Retrieve data from the database
    .GroupBy(
        keySelector: resultSet => new { userId = resultSet.userId }, 
        elementSelector: resultSet => resultSet)
    .ToList();

Note that the `ToList()` method is called before the `GroupBy()` method to retrieve the data from the database and convert it into a list. After this, the `GroupBy()` method is applied to the resulting list.
```

Comment: I'm interested in calling to list after the grouping clause

Comment: @locx, actually it is proper solution. Grouping items on the server side has no sense here. SQL can return only grouping key and aggregation result. Other operators may lead to performance degradation. Here you retrieve ALL items, so better to do grouping on the  client side.